# Interested in back end. Got front end job. Dilemma

Tags: internship

I applied at a company for an internship. I mentioned them that I am particularly interested in back end, and coding complex algorithms in general.

They reverted back saying they have chosen my profile for UI intern instead as it matches more closely according to their company specs. Being in need of a job I continued the process. Completed take home project and Skype interview, I got the position. They offered me the position and I accepted it.

But now I am having second thoughts about it. Whether I should join or not ? I raised this issue with them stating that I want more development like projects but less website designing. They said it will be a combination of both but focus on JS will be lot higher. The company is good, but I am having a dilemma as what to do. Should I go ? How much different is actually Back End from Front End ? Will I be choosing a wrong path ?

I am concerned.

Comment: What country are you in? How many other opportunities for internships do you have?

Comment: India. Currently I do not have any other internship opportunities.

Comment: @Joe, Yes I am always determined to work hard. That's not a problem. I am only concerned, whether taking up this job would effect my career in any negative way. I don't know anything about software industry. That's why I am seeking advice.

Comment: @Joe - Yes, currently I have only one option. The thing is that if I take this job, will it go as a no development experience from point of view of back end community ? I mean in future while applying for a backbend job, will this experience from internship would be considered as invalid, or will it carry some weight? They saying that you will be spending most of the time coding in JS rather than designing. Also some time you will also indulge into ruby development as a middle ware. For back end I do use node, so I think this internship won't be a total waste. Right ?

Comment: @Joe - Yes I think so. Thanks for the help :) Will definitely work hard.

Comment: @sgoel To program in any language you still have to design something. GUI code needs design just like algorithm-oriented code does.

Comment: This is silly. You have opportunity to learn, so make it happen.

Comment: @Student T - Thanks for the fire. I needed just that

Comment: @sgoel You don't get to call the shots if you are an intern, or for that matter, even when you have several years of experience. The company is hiring you to get their job done, not to give you what you want. Making such demands is quite silly. If you don't like the work they are offering, take up a different internship which is more in line with what you want.

Comment: Since they require you to have more knowledge on Js, this will be beneficial for you not only on front-end but also in backend because you can also write code on server side in JavaScript in Nodejs. As per me you will be Full Stack Engineer in no time.

Comment: @MaskedMan Yes you are correct, but my situation is such that opportunities also don't come in the way I want.

Comment: @Mozak Thanks Mozak, that will definitely help me in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a backend developer, it is still very good/important to know what goes on in the frontend. Having an opportunity to learn that part first-hand is very valuable for the future. You will learn to anticipate what features frontend devs will likely request and need. This allows you to design the backend with this already in mind and you will make better design choices.

And it is even more critical if you later work as a full stack developer. Instead of having the pressure of completing the backend features all the while learning how frontend works, you already know about both and can work far more effectively and with less stress.

Comment: Thanks very much Juha, for the support. I never had a mentor in my college, that's why it is difficult me to find the right advice. I am always making decisions on my own no matter how skewed they are. This will help me.